# Setting attached property in App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I have the following app.xaml:

```
<BaseApp x:Class ="MyApp"
         xmlns ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:MyApp"
        Props.MyCustom="test"
         Startup ="Application_Startup"                                 
         >

<Application.Resources >
    < ResourceDictionary>
        ...
    </ ResourceDictionary>        

</Application.Resources>
```

I then need to be able to read the property from the base application:

```
 public partial class BaseApp : Application
{        

      static void MyFunc()
      {
           // Access property from here
           var myvar = Props.MyCustom
      }
}
```

I'm currently working on the belief that this needs to be in a separate class, as follows:

```
 public class Props : DependencyObject
{
    public string MyCustom
    {
        get { return ( string)GetValue(MyCustomProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCustomPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey MyCustomPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("MyCustom" , typeof (string ), typeof (Props), new UIPropertyMetadata (0));           

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty = MyCustomPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

}
```

Am I approaching this in the right way, and if so, what do I need to do to be able to access this from app.xaml?

EDIT:

For future travellers, the way I finally managed this was to simply declare an abstract read-only property in the base class and override it in code behind.  Not as neat as I would have liked, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached properties should have static getter and setter methods, in your case:

```
public static string GetMyCustom(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (string)obj.GetValue(MyCustomProperty);
}

public static void SetMyCustom(DependencyObject obj, string value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MyCustomProperty, value);
}
```

---

Having said that you would still have to have an instance of a `DependencyObject`-derived class to set the property on, which `System.Windows.Application` is not. In other words, you can't set an attached property on your MyApp object.

---

Instead of using an attached property, you might just add a plain CLR property to your `BaseApp` class:

```
public class BaseApp : Application
{
    public string MyCustom { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<local:BaseApp x:Class="MyNamespace.MyApp" ...
               MyCustom="Hello">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</local:BaseApp>
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible to do this with attached properties, or that it is not possible to do this at all?

Comment: Exactly. Attached properties are dependency properties and can therefore only by set on instances of classes that derive from `DependencyObject`.

Comment: That then brings me back to be initial question of "Am I approaching this in the right way?"  Is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: No idea, as you haven't told us why you want to set a property on your application instance. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Fair point.  I've edited my post, but effectively, I'm trying to set-up a base application that will execute some common functionality, but it needs a piece of information from the child app at runtime (hence the custom property)

Comment: You could just add a plain property to your BaseApp class. See my edit.

Comment: I initially tried that, but it causes a crash.  My assumption at the time was that it was because touching the property was causing the app to start-up before I was ready for it to do so.